# Getting data out of devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I'm migrating away from rails. I will be using the same domain, so I'll get the `_session_id` cookie that rails uses and I can bring over the old `sessions` table.I would like to use this to extract data (the `user_id`) from the old session. I can not tell how to do this outside of rails.

Within a controller there's `current_user` of course or `session["warden.user.user.key"]`, but how can I take the id, decrypt the data in the table, and pull stuff out on my own (besides running the old rails application and creating a route on that that returns the info I need and hitting it from my new application)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is the best way, but I was intrigued so went down the rabbit hole. This works for my 4.1.10 app where sessions are stored in the cookie. You'll want to look at action pack's EncryptedCookieJar class and active support's CachingKeyGenerator and MessageEncryptor classes for details.

Obviously you'll need to replace the two strings that start "THE VALUE…".

```
key_generator = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new('THE VALUE OF SECRET_KEY_BASE FROM config/secrets.yml', iterations: 1000)
caching_key_generator = ActiveSupport::CachingKeyGenerator.new(key_generator)
caching_key_generator.generate_key('encrypted cookie')
caching_key_generator.generate_key('signed encrypted cookie')
secret = caching_key_generator.generate_key('encrypted cookie')
sign_secret = caching_key_generator.generate_key('signed encrypted cookie')
encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, sign_secret, serializer: ActionDispatch::Cookies::NullSerializer)
session_value = CGI::unescape('THE VALUE OF THE SESSION COOKIE')
serialized_result = encryptor.decrypt_and_verify(session_value)
result = Marshal.load(serialized_result)
```

The `result`, for me, is a hash that looks exactly the session hash in Rails.

If it doesn't work for you, you may be using a different serializer so need to replace `Marshal.load` with whatever you need.  Just take a look at `serialized_result` and see.

Comment: I'm on Rails 3.2.18, are the classes different? What do I have to require?

Comment: They may well be. You'll have to go down the rabbit hole yourself I'm afraid.